# how to find delta when the force of interest is unknown

Tags: finance

An investment of 1000 accumulates to 1360.86 at the end of five years. If the force of interest is δ during the first year and 1.5δ in each subsequent year. How to find δ?

Comment: Is "the force of interest" the interest rate?

Comment: @fae The result is 4.5%. If you are interested in a (right) answer give a reply. Btw, isn´t the number 1360.8**6**?

Comment: @callculus yess it is 1360.86

Comment: @callculus  this is my calculation 1000(e^delta)(e^1.5delta)^4 = 1360.86 and the delta value i got is 0.04401669...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the integral at the exponent.

$$1000\cdot e^{\int_0^1 \delta \ ds +4\cdot \int_0^1 1.5\cdot \delta \ ds}=1360.86$$

Dividing the equation by 1000 the equation becomes

$$e^{\int_0^1 \delta \  ds +4\cdot \int_0^1 1.5\cdot \delta \ ds}=1.36086$$

$$e^{7\cdot \delta}=1.36086$$
$$7\cdot \delta=\ln(1.36086)$$
$$\delta=\frac{1}{7}\cdot \ln(1.36086)\approx 0.04401669$$

It seems that you haven´t omitted the integrals at your calculation if I compare our results. So I can confirm your result. Can you now find the equivalent annual effective interest rate in the first year?

Comment: (1+i)^5 = e^(0.04401669326)(5) and the effective rate i got is 0.04499979914

Comment: Only for the fiirst year. But at the end your result is right. $$(1+i)=e^{\Large{\int_0^1 0.0440166932 \ d \delta } }=1.045$$

Comment: what does the 1.045 value for

Comment: @fae This is $1+i$. Therefore the annual interest rate is $i=0.045=4.5\%$. Don´t forget to mark this answer as accepted. This is necessary since the totally wrong answer of Patricio has 3 upvotes. Very misleading.

Answer (score 3):

You need to solve the equation

$$1000 (1+\delta)(1+1.5\delta)^4=1360.80$$

(I get $4.54225\%$)

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with force of interest.

Comment: @callculus I've just assumed that the interest is annually compounded rather than continuously compounded as you do